# Python model with a list of self references

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to do something like this:

```
class Author(db.Model):
    influencedBy = db.ListProperty(db.SelfReferenceProperty())
    influenced = db.ListProperty(db.SelfReferenceProperty())
```

I know I can use self.author_set to get the reverse relationship, but I need to add multiple Author objects to influenced and influencedBy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do what you propose. As you probably have realized you will get `ValueError: Item type ReferenceProperty is not acceptable`

You could do `influencedBy = db.ListProperty(db.Key)`
or if you used ndb  `influencedBy = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Author,repeated=True)`

Once thing to consider is how many members might be in `influencedBy` and `influenced`. If its possible for there to be large numbers then you might run into entity size issues. If that is a possibility you then need to consider using a separate entity to record influence.